# Is there any way to strike superscripted references properly with latexdiff?

Tags: superscripts, latexdiff

I am using latexdiff to keep track of changes in my LaTeX documents. Superscripted references are striked on the same level as normal text, making them appear underlined. I want to get rid of this behaviour but don't know how.

[image: mwe]

MWE:

`old.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[superscript,biblabel]{cite}

\begin{document}
When moving a superscripted reference, and checking the changes 
with latexdiff, the reference is not striked in superscript. It 
will appear underlined.\cite{lamport94}

That bugs me.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{lamport94}
  Leslie Lamport,
  \emph{\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System}.
  Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
  2nd Edition,
  1994.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

`new.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[superscript,biblabel]{cite}

\begin{document}
When moving a superscripted reference, and checking the changes 
with latexdiff, the reference is not striked in superscript. It 
will appear underlined.

That bugs me.\cite{lamport94}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{lamport94}
  Leslie Lamport,
  \emph{\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System}.
  Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,
  2nd Edition,
  1994.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

generating `diff.tex`:

```
latexdiff old.tex new.tex > diff.tex
```

Comment: The striking out in latexdiff is done with the "ulem" package and there is nothing I can do about this directly as author of latexdiff.  You should contact "ulem" maintainers about a bug of the \sout command, i.e. write to them that in '...underlined\sout{^1}.' you expect the 1 to be struck out rather than underlined.

Comment: @frederik: thank you very much for getting in touch with me. I will contact the ulem maintainer.

Comment: @frederik when I played around with this question a bit I considered to write a custom `markoverwith` ulem command with a raised strikethrough and then to insert an alternative `\DIFadd`/`\DIFdel` command containing the new command (instead of `\sout`) if the `DIFAUXCMD` is a `\cite` (if `usepackage[superscript]{cite}` is present). Unfortunately, I could not figure out how to modify latexdiff to do this. Do you think it would be a practical approach to the question?

Comment: @Marijn  this could be possible in principle but adds complexity to the latexdiff (internal) work flow and configuration, so I am not sure if the added complexity is justified to gain this functionality. Currently the only specialised flavour of \DIFadd commands is within floats, and one would have to add another class like this. From the latexdiff side easier to implement would be to define an alternative \cite command that produces the struck-out superscript, and then replace the standarc \cite with the modified \cite when within a \DIFdel (or \DIFadd) argument.

Comment: @Marijn (continued from above). This is the way the highlighting of figures is implemented: the \includegraphics is redefined whenever entering a \DIFadd, \DIFdel sequence (see the latexdiff source for details).  In any case, if you want to pursue this raise an 'issue' on the github page of latexdiff, if you would like to take the discussion further.

Comment: @frederik @Marijn  I received an email from the `ulem` dev. He will not fix this problem in the `ulem` package.